# How to remove old repository URL from MercurialEclipse plugins repository location field

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I've a mercurial repository to which I push my changes with eclipses MercurialEclipse plugin, using Team -> Push. Now the repository URL has changed, and eclipse always remembers the old url in the input field, which is preselected as default, and I need to select the new one from the pull down list. Very small problem, but annoying none the less.. Is there a way to clear the old value from the field, so that I don't always need to pick the URL manually until the end of time?

Alternatively, how to change the default repository entry to be the new one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found out myself that you can change the default by right clicking on repository -> properties -> mercurial -> change default repository. Also allows for deleting the old repository URL from the same interface.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other answers work, you can go to `[your_eclipse_workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse` and look at repositories.txt and the corresponding repositories.txt for the project.

I deleted some URLs in both, and now they've disappeared :)

Comment: In more recent incarnations of MercurialEclipse the passwords seem to be stores in the .key file in the path you describe (I did not see the .txt files you mention). Deleting this or renaming it also has the effect of removing old passwords.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Helios team synchronize view you can click on "Synchronize..." from the toolbar. This will let you switch the repo used for sync.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Mars I solved it this way:

- You Simply clone repository as a new one.
- Old repository you can *right click->Remove*. Mercurial doesn't remove the content. Only the his own metadata. So it is safe operation. (In Git be careful and do hard copy for certainty.)
- In project Explorer on the project *right click->Properties* we cannot modify repository but we can add or remove another one.
- In menu above *Project->Clean* (whole workspace).
- Restart Eclipse.

Maybe some steps are obsolete, but the old repository was very resistant for removal. So I described all steps which I used.